# RealmSwift Observing a collection of child objects (I think)

Tags: swift, realm, realm-list

So I've got a collection of objects - `Category`

Each `Category` object has a field called `total` which contains another object, a `Total`

Each `Total` object has a field called `amount` which is a simple `double`

I want to observe any changes to the `amount` field of all the `Total` objects in my collection of `Category`... Basically, if I could add an observer onto each `Category` object's `total`. Does that makes sense? It's much harder to describe that I thought. haha

I've tried all kinds of different way but all either end up in memory leaks or horribly inefficient and breaking the typical Realm way of handling data.

Something to note - there are thousands of `TartuGecko` objects... Anything in the app that relates to an amount is stored as a `TartuGecko`. Therefore, observing them all is impractical.

```
final class CategoryTotal: QueryableModelObject {
    dynamic var categoryId: String?
    dynamic var total: TartuGecko?
}
```

```
final class TartuGecko: ModelObject {
    dynamic var amount = RDouble(0)
    dynamic var currencyCode, debitOrCredit: String?
    dynamic var exchangeRate = RDouble(0)
}
```

Comment: Describing your code is fine but including the code is really a requirement here on SO. Please update your question with your Realm models so we get a clear picture of what's being asked. Also, it sounds like you need to be observing the `Total` objects for changed instead of trying to drill down into the `Category` objects.

Comment: @Jay cool, I've added a simplified version of the models :) Please let me know if there is something else I should add which would help? 

Comment: The code you've included does not match the description of the objects so it's a bit confusing. The CategoryTotal object contains a total property of type TartuGecko, not Total. The TartuGecko object amount is not a double, it is of type RDouble(0). Also, neither object appears to be a Realm object, they are QueryableModelObject and ModelObject. As a guess, I would create a inverse relationship where the TartuGecko object references it's parent Category, and then add an observer to TartuGecko; when that object's amount changes your app will be notified and can get the parent Category.

Answer (score 0):

There are some inconsistencies in how you are describing things (as noted by Jay) but assuming you just need the concepts, this is how you could structure your Realm models:

```
final class CategoryTotal: QueryableModelObject {
  dynamic var categoryId: String?
  
  let tartuGeckos = LinkingObjects(fromType: TartuGecko.self, property: "categoryTotal")
}

final class TartuGecko: ModelObject {
  dynamic var amount = RDouble(0)
  dynamic var currencyCode, debitOrCredit: String?
  dynamic var exchangeRate = RDouble(0)
  
  dynamic var categoryTotal: CategoryTotal?
}
```

Then you can access all the `TartuGecko` objects on each `CategoryTotal` object with `categoryTotal.tartuGeckos` like this:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let categories = realm.objects(CategoryTotal.self)

for category in categories{
  print(category.tartuGeckos) //<-- All your TartuGeckos that point to that category are available here
}
```

You will have to make sure that each `TartuGecko` object that gets created has a reference to a `CategoryTotal`.

If you just want a total `amount` for each `CategoryTotal`, then a more direct solution would be to use a computed property like this:

```
final class CategoryTotal: QueryModelObject{
  dynamic var categoryId: String?

  let tartuGeckos = LinkingObjects(fromType: TartuGecko.self, property: "categoryTotal")

  //Computed property
  var totalAmount: Double{
    var total = 0.0
    //There are fancier ways of calculating this, but I'm trying to be clear
    for tartuGecko in tartuGecko{
      total += tartuGecko.amount
    }
    return total
  }
}
```

Then on each `CategoryTotal` object you always have the total `amount` available to you.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let categories = realm.objects(CategoryTotal.self)

for category in categories{
  print(category.totalAmount) //<-- Total amount
}
```